# I need to view S3 images using react website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3

I am learning some new languages and creating a react website for fun.  right now it uses some images just from a local folder and its just running locally on my mac.  I have an AWS account and created a non public S3 bucket and copied each of the images I use to it.  My question is how to I use the S3 bucket images in a react website?

I was hoping to keep the bucket non public and was thinking I could use the AWS SDK to still use the image url with proper authentication?  I assume if I made the bucket public its as easy as using the image url?

so anyone have a good example of just using images from an S3 bucket in react app.  Ideally a private bucket that I pass creds to?  or tell me I need my bucket public.  I dont see many examples outside of trying to upload and download images which for now I dont need to do

Comment: If you don't have much experience with AWS then a public bucket would be the simplest. The other option is using AWS Cognito identity federation to login (via username and password), then receive temporary IAM credentials that you could then use to authenticate against a private bucket and retrieve an item.

Comment: Is the normal process for using S3 for static website images to leave it public. I was trying to follow best practice.

Comment: There isn't really a "normal" process when it comes to these sorts of things. It really depends on your application and/or business needs. In one of my current apps I serve all content from a Cloudfront CDN and the bucket itself is private and only Cloudfront has access to serve images. Other applications I've served directly from a public bucket. If all you're wanting to do is serve up some images to your web app and the images aren't private, there there isn't much reason to keep it private.

Comment: I setup cloudfront and it worked exactly like I wanted.  thanks